# How to declare multiple template parameters with c++11 function callback

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-c++

I need to declare function which will take several tasks, split on few cores and return vector of results:

```
template <typename T, typename R>
void execInParallel(vector<T> &tasks, vector<R> &res,function<R(T &t)>fn, int cores) {
   // ...
}
```

MSVC 2015 can't find out that `R` and `T` should be `int` in this simple case:

```
vector<int> tasks,res;
execInParallel(tasks,res, [&](int&t) {
    int r = 0;
    return r;
}, 2);
```

and gives me these errors:

```
error C2672: 'execInParallel': no matching overloaded function found

error C2784: 'void execInParallel(std::vector<_Type,std::allocator<_Ty>> &,std::vector<R,std::allocator<_Other>> &,std::function<R(T &)>,int)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::function<R(T &)>' from 'main::<lambda_cd8cffeb725f03d56af913e6045a67ff>'
```

How should I declare `execInParallel` so I can pass there array of tasks and results and callback to execute one task?

Comment: If you aren't going to store the `std::function` anywhere, perhaps making it a separate template parameter may be better (as in don't use std::function at all). At the very least, it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename F>
void execInParallel(vector<T> &tasks, vector<R> &res, F&& f, int cores) {
  function<R(T &t)> fn(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is emitted because `function<R(T &t)>` cannot be deduced from a lambda.

To fix it, you can make this parameter in a non-deduced context by using an `Identity` class, for example,

```
template <typename T>
struct Identity {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
using Identity_t = typename Identity<T>::type;

template <typename T, typename R>
void execInParallel(vector<T> &tasks, vector<R> &res, Identity_t<function<R(T &t)>> fn, int cores);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda is not a std::function. So try to define the function before using it like:

std::function func= ->int { ... };
execInParallel(tasks, res, func, 2);